# What is the Shiva Stuti?

Tags: shiva

What is the Shiva Stuti?

Please explain what the Shiva Stuti is.

Comment: Which Shiva Stuti? You did not mention any

Comment: @Rickross Sorry I don't know what is Shiva Stuti in the first place? What is Shiva Stuti?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Yeah, what is it and where is it taken from?

Comment: Stuti means praise